# USB not detected by i.mx 287 EVK (FreeScale) board

Tags: linux, usb, arm

I am using i.mx 287 EVK from freescale for my application development.

I am ported linux kernel and rootfs successfully.

But the problem is my hardware does't detect the USB stick if connected.

Nothing changes in /dev directory nor anything appears in log (dmesg).

Kindly help me resolve it.

Hardware has both usb host and device ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic things i would check :

- Check with other USB.
- Connect a USB Mouse or USB keyboard. Check if they are working. Check if the devices are getting power or not.
- If you are not getting the power, definitely there is a problem with the kernel configuration.

Do `make menuconfig` from the linux folder, go to **USB drivers section** and **enable all the flags that are needed for a USB pendrive to work.**

Easy method would be to take the configuration file(kconfig) of a working linux kernel, copy it inside your kernel, compile it and run it. It should work

ITs been a while that i did the above things. But this should help you out of your current problem.

Comment: I would be glad to know the reason for Downvote. Please mention the reason.